# AngularJS $stateParams when using reloadOnSearch:false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, angular-ui-router

I have a page in my application which uses a search so i have added the ***"realoadOnSearch:false"*** which works perfectly

The problem I have is when navigating to the same state with a different stateParam:

when I navigate to ***#/category/20/*** from any other page it works fine... i then have a link on that page to ***#/category/3*** (the parent category for 20) and the URL updates, however the content does not (no console errors)

***app.js (main application)***

```
        .state('category', {
            url: '/category/:categoryId/',
            templateUrl: '/Home/Category',
            controller: 'categoryCtrl',
            reloadOnSearch: false
        })
```

I have tried adding ***target="_self"*** to force page reload and it does not work

I have also tried to watch ***$stateParams*** for changes and there is nothing

Clicking the link to ***#/category/3*** from ***#/category/20*** (and vice versa) should navigate to the new page and reload the data, where search should **NOT** reload the page (latter works but not the former)

The URL is prefered to be a ng-href rather than ng-click as it is managed by the root controller

**EDIT:**

I did not find a direct solution, however i just disabled the reloadOnSearch and my sorting buttons still work so this works for me for now as a solution.

Comment: Do the $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess events fire?

Comment: I tried listening to both events from $rootScope on run and no events are fired =/ @NevilleS

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `reloadOnSearch` doesn't do what you think it does; it's actually more like `reloadOnStateParams`. Setting it to false prevents you from making state changes where only the `stateParams` change, which is what you're doing here (going from `#/category/3` to `#/category/20`).

You can see this documented on the UI router issues page: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1079

There's some workarounds in there but none of them are great. You are probably best off using an ng-click that forces a reload manually, something like this:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
  reload: true,
  inherit: false,
  notify: true
});
```

Comment: I have done as you said and even them i am still not able to move. i even manually set the $stateParams.categoryId and it still stays put. the event gets fired on ng-click. im trying a few more things and ill get back here with updates

Comment: Depending on your state definitions, ui router might be actively preventing you from doing this. I'd recommend you set a breakpoint in `$state.transitionTo` and step through the logic there, especially the `shouldTriggerReload` logic. It looks like `reloadOnSearch` might supersede all the `reload` options you provide...